# Extra space preceding change of language in XəLaΤεχ Polyglossia

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

I am writing in Portuguese with some English words thrown in.  The issue is that when a line with English text breaks, the English text gets preceded by extra spacing:

```latex
\documentclass {scrbook}

\usepackage {polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage {portuguese}
\setotherlanguage {english}


\begin {document}
no \textenglish {Hillsdale college}, na primavera de 2006, e sou grato
ao professor \textenglish {Donald Westblade} pela oportunidade de
palestrar em minha

\end {document}
```

Results in something like ‘no__Hillsdale college’, where __ denotes extra spacing.

Comment: The spacing looks right to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihi58.png What version of polyglossia are you using?

Comment: I get no extra spacing with version v1.47 of `polyglossia` (which was released not that long ago). There was an issue with version 1.46 (https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/356 and linked issues) that could cause unwanted white space with some language switching commands. Consider updating your system to get `polyglossia` v1.47.

Comment: The issue was due to a bug that had already been fixed and has been solved with a software update

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is a Polyglossia 1.46 bug.  Installing a user local 1.47 with tlmgr solved the issue, even if it caused another one.